# Why is port not open? ufw disabled, service running

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, localhost

I have a mysql service running on `ubuntu` server on port `33070`.
I can connect to it locally, but not from outside(another machine).

Here is what I've tried.

1. `ufw` is off

```
root@localhost:/# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

2. service is running

```
root@localhost:/# sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :33070
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      81379/docker-proxy
```

3. `telnet` on server

```
root@localhost:/# telnet localhost 33070
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
Wn7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4?R^9J4
```

4. `telnet` from my local machine

```
myuser@my-MacBook-Pro / % telnet serverIp 33070
Trying serverIp...
telnet: connect to address serverIp: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Why I have timeout when trying to connect to `33070` port from my local machine and what else should be configured on the server?

Another thing which I've tried is

I've also a service running on server `33066` port, which is open and available from my local machine.
And all the above commands looks like the same for `33066` except the last one.

```
myuser@my-MacBook-Pro / % telnet serverIp 33066
Trying serverIp...
Connected to serverIp.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
X['bu%)^mysql_native_password
```

Comment: ufw might be off, but you are running Docker ("docker-proxy"). Docker itself changes a lot of network settings and turns the server into a router (to route containers). It's not as simple as just running a service. Nothing you wrote can help solve this problem magically. Start there: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/